# How to run a AWS Lambda after 2 hours

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 Lambda, The first Lambda for loading data into my GBQ, And the second Lambda need to be run after that 2 hours to check the data on GBQ. 
I have investigated it but seems like we can schedule using Rate or Cron, but I want to run the second Lambda only once.
Is there another way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate and corn is one option with adding the cloud watch with the Lambda function but according to your requirement you can make it something like

When lambda one trigger and complete execution you can add code with endpoint of another lambda. as you want to run it after two hour you can set time using [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).so one lambda one will be trigger after that it will trigger lambda two function using the end point where time of 2 hour manage by [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).

if you are using python then you can use a scheduler

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...Triggering another lambda end point")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You can also use the cloud watch to trigger lambda at specific time. Set cron using the cloud watch event

Answer (score 3):

According to your requirement, you can use AWS Step Functions Wait state to coordinate the two lambda functions:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html